# How to clear the memory that was allocated for a QVBoxLayout properly

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I have a method that creates a new window with some buttons, a line edit, etc.

```cpp
QWidget* wid = new QWidget;
QVBoxLayout* vbLog = new QVBoxLayout(wid);
QLineEdit* tlLogin = new QLineEdit("your login");
QLineEdit* tlPassword = new QLineEdit("your password");
QPushButton* btnLog = new QPushButton("LogIn");
QLabel* lbl = new QLabel();

lbl->setAlignment(Qt::AlignCenter);
wid->setWindowModality(Qt::ApplicationModal);
wid->resize(200, 100);

wid->setAttribute(Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose, true);
tlLogin->setAttribute(Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose, true);
tlPassword->setAttribute(Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose, true);
btnLog->setAttribute(Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose, true);
lbl->setAttribute(Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose, true);

vbLog->addWidget(tlLogin);
vbLog->addWidget(tlPassword);
vbLog->addWidget(btnLog);
vbLog->addWidget(lbl);

vbLog->setAlignment(Qt::AlignTop | Qt::AlignLeft);
wid->setLayout(vbLog);
wid->show();
```

I delete all pointers to variables as soon as the window closes:

```
wid->setAttribute(Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose, true);
tlLogin->setAttribute(Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose, true);
tlPassword->setAttribute(Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose, true);
btnLog->setAttribute(Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose, true);
lbl->setAttribute(Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose, true);
```

Am I doing the right thing, or is it better not to use this practice?

The most interesting thing is that `QVBoxLayout` does not have a `setAttribute` method, and I do not know how to remove it properly. Does it only remain to declare it as a member of the class and delete it only in the destructor?

I would not like to declare it as a class member, since `QVBoxLayout` can accumulate a lot and it will be inconvenient.

Comment: Usually you don't need to delete any `QWidget` or `QLayout` except your top-level widget. FYI: [Object Trees & Ownership](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/objecttrees.html). (The only exception are `QAction`s which are sharable.)

Comment: @Scheff'sCat so I don't need this code?
   
`wid->setAttribute(Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose, true);

    tlLogin->setAttribute(Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose, true);

    tlPassword->setAttribute(Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose, true);

    btnLog->setAttribute(Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose, true);

    lbl->setAttribute(Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose, true);`

Comment: Only `wid->setAttribute(Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose, true);` is required. `wid` will delete the rest itself because everything is its direct child or its grandchild (via `vbLog`).

Comment: What I am saying applies to all subclasses of `QObject` with a parent/child relationship. There is no magic behind it: when you create your own classes and add custom properties to them or if you somehow have `QObject`s that are not parent/child of one another, Qt won't know what to delete for you.